# Groovy Script Assertion for XML response using soapui?

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I was working only with JSON response and for validation I was using below script. Now i need to do similar validation for XML response. How to achieve this for XML?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 

def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText response

assert json.name == "ABCD"
assert json.status == "Success"
```

Comment: Please show the sample xml response

Comment: Sorry Rao, As of now i dont have any response to share with you. Could you please take one simple example and share.

Comment: There are lot of answer with that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1702943+%5Bgroovy%5DxmlSlurper)

Comment: Thanks Rao, I will gothrough each link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.10/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) class that is very similar to `JsonSlurper`. Assuming this is  your's XML, you can do something like this:

```
def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
  <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
</breakfast_menu>
'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

assert root.food[0].name.text() == 'Belgian Waffles'
```

Keep in mind that `new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)` returns a node that refers to the first (root) XML node element. Then you can do almost the same manipulations that are available for `JsonSlureper` class.

Comment: Thanks, So between JSON and XML response, which one is best practice with respect to API testing?